# Am I using concat correctly in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, vector, concatenation

The method below is returning a path, but I don't want to recalculate paths if there is a same path to the same tile (to reduce processing)

```
   public function find_path(start:Path_Tiles,end:Path_Tiles,R_G_B:Number,SCAREDNESS:Number = 1,enemie_type:Number=1, enemie_colour:Number=1):Vector.<Path_Tiles> 
    {
        for (var i:Number = 0 ; i < old_path_array_other_info.length ; i++ )
        {
            if (old_path_array_other_info[i][0] == enemie_type && old_path_array_other_info[i][1] == enemie_colour && old_path_array_other_info[i][2] == start.x && old_path_array_other_info[i][3] == start.y)
            {
                var new_vector:Vector.<Path_Tiles> = (old_path_array[i]).concat();
                return new_vector;
            }
        }
        old_path_array[old_path_array.length] = path_finder.Find_Path(Gird.TILE_SET, start, end, R_G_B, SCAREDNESS);
        old_path_array_other_info[old_path_array_other_info.length] = [enemie_type, enemie_colour, start.x, start.y];

        return old_path_array[old_path_array.length - 1];
    }
```

The reason in need to use concat is I don't want to return the exact same path that a enemy is using because the enemy will remove elements from the array after it reaches the point. So I need a copy of it, but the method above doesn't give a copy of the path it return the exact same path, meaning that when a enemy uses the old path half of it is deleted so making it useless.

Any help would be great because I'm not sure if I'm using concat correctly.

Comment: concat creates a copy of the current targeted Array/vector but it is not recursive meaning it doesn't create also copies of any Array/Vector you might have stored inside the targeted Array/Vector. If you have some kind of multidimensional Array/Vector then you'll have to go through each one and call concat on it or else you won't get a true copy.

Comment: @BotMaster Thanks for the reply, that do you mean when you say "you might have stored inside the targeted Array/Vector"?

Comment: I only mean if you have a multidimensional Array/Vector and you call concat on it, that Array/Vector will be copied but not the ones that are inside of it. Like: myarray = []; myarray[0] = ['hello']; mycopy = myarray.concat(); mycopy is a true copy of myarray but the array inside of it (['hello']) is not.

Comment: @BotMaster I'm not 100% sure on what you mean  in your example. but is ("Vector.<Path_Tiles>") impossible to get a true copy. But I don't think "Vector.<Path_Tiles>" is not  multidimensional (I think) because it only holds a list of Path_Tiles

Comment: let me put it simpler, this: (old_path_array[i]).concat() is a Vector.<Path_Tiles> and concat makes a copy of this Vector.<Path_Tiles> but it does not copy its content so every single Path_Tiles Object and whatever they reference is not a copy, that's all.

Comment: @BotMaster Thanks (this is my last Yes or No question) is there a way to copy the Path_Tiles inside the old_path_array? sorry for being annoying .

Comment: Not by default, you'll have to come up with your own implementation but either way Vector.concat() won't be able to generate those copies, you'll have to go through the vector and copy them yourself. I don't know how complex this Path_Tiles class is but you should be able to implement some sort of clone() method.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above:

`concat` creates a copy of the current targeted Array/vector but it is not recursive meaning it doesn't create also copies of any Array/Vector you might have stored inside the targeted Array/Vector. If you have some kind of multidimensional Array/Vector, then you'll have to go through each one and call `concat` on it or else you won't get a true copy.

If you have a multidimensional Array/Vector and you call concat on it, that Array/Vector will be copied but not the ones that are inside of it. Like:

```
myarray = []; 
myarray[0] = ['hello']; 
mycopy = myarray.concat();
```

mycopy is a true copy of myarray but the array inside of it `(['hello'])` is not.

```
(old_path_array[i]).concat()
```

is a Vector. `<Path_Tiles>` and `concat` makes a copy of this Vector, but it does not copy its content so every single `<Path_Tiles>` object and whatever they reference is not a copy, that's all.

**References**

- [Optimizing Performance for the Flash Platform: Vector class versus Array class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS4bebcd66a74275c3a0f5f19124318fc87b-7fff.html)